# Is using a fixed random seed in production okay?

Tags: clustering, gaussian-mixture-distribution, randomness, generalized-moments

I have a dataset and am trying to use GMM to cluster it. The algorithm works well but when I run it multiple times I get different results. While the clusters produced in each run are valid my users are unhappy with the non determinism.

I am tempted to use a constant random seed but other threads mostly suggest to use a fixed random seed only while testing/evaluating the model, not in production (although I haven't seen anyone discuss this in the setting of clustering). Is using a fixed random seed the correct solution? And why is it deemed an incorrect solution in other settings?

I have tried other methods to try to reduce the non determinism like cleaning the data, using the previous run's results as the input but those don't seem too useful and cause other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more about your situation, my suggestion is to allow users to either set their known seed, or set a completely random seed at each run (your current setup), or use a default random seed. If you make this last option the default, users will get the same results from the same dataset but they still have the option to explore the variability associated with the seed.

If this flexibility cannot be implemented then I don't think there is a definitive answer because it depends on your specific case.

In practice, you may be in a situation where different seeds give effectively identical results that only look annoyingly different. The differences could simply be that the same clusters get different arbitrary names or plots are rotated or clusters are coloured differently. If you are confident this is the case then I guess it's ok to fix the seed. Where fixing the seed could mean, I don't know, using the md5 sum of the input data.

Comment: Thank you! Because pretty much each clustering the model produces is (almost) equally valid, I think I'll use a fixed/chosen by user seed. My follow up question is why aren't these options explored more in the literature. Is randomness not a problem for most machine learning algorithms used in the real world (i.e production env)?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't set seeds, then the pseudorandom number generator would start with a different 'unknowable' seed for each simulation. Setting seeds guarantees reproducibility of a particular simulation. [Using R.]

```
set.seed(1); rbinom(10, 5, .5)
 [1] 2 2 3 4 2 4 4 3 3 1
set.seed(1); rbinom(10, 5, .5)
 [1] 2 2 3 4 2 4 4 3 3 1
```

However, skeptics may wonder if you shopped around for a seed that gave a particularly 'nice' result. I have seen textbooks with nice results that seem 'too good to be true'. (One example is in fudging a small sample that adheres very closely to the Empirical Rule, or some such relationship.)  Below, the instructor might be 'shopping' for results
close to $\mu \pm \sigma$ or $(90, 110).$

```
set.seed(1); quantile(rnorm(59, 100, 10), c(.17,.83))
      17%       83% 
 93.64824 108.29605

set.seed(2); quantile(rnorm(59, 100, 10), c(.17,.83))
      17%       83% 
 90.78224 111.58338   

set.seed(3); quantile(rnorm(59, 100, 10), c(.17,.83))
      17%       83% 
 90.35638 109.02981    # THIS 'dataset' is shown to the class.

set.seed(4); quantile(rnorm(59, 100, 10), c(.17,.83))
      17%       83% 
 93.74339 112.42379
```

In some applications, using the same seed repeatedly may result in
unintended dependence.

```
set.seed(1)                # This month
x = rnorm(100, 50, 7)

set.seed(1)                # Again next month
y = c(rnorm(98, 40, 7), 40, 40)
cor(x,y)
[1] 0.9893361              # spurious (near 1)

set.seed(1)                          
x = rnorm(100, 50, 7)

set.seed(2)                # Fresh seed next month
y = c(rnorm(98, 50, 7), 40, 40)
cor(x,y)
[1] -0.1399602             # reasonable (near 0)
```

One practice that provides reproducibility with minimal
risk of suspicion or spurious correlation is to use routinely today's time/date (hhdd, ddmm, mmyy, or yyyy) as the seed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although I don't think it answers my original question. While you have described a possible abuse of a fixed seed and the dangers of seed reuse, my question remains: Is using a fixed seed in a production ML system okay given the client's request of determinism? Could it have any downsides? For example deteriorating the validity of the clusters generated?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by a 'ML system', in order to avoid spurious correlations, each separate simulation should have its own seed (which you could reveal). A more informative Question, might yield better-targeted answers. In particular, you might elaborate on the relevance of your second paragraph. // The fact that the risk of spurious correlation may not be immediately obvious, does not mean there is no such risk. // Make a list of seeds in advance and do not change them after you see results.